# graph coloring conjecture

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

**Motivation**: if smallest planar graph $G=(v,e)$ exist with $\chi(G)$ = 5, then $\delta(G) > 4$ and $\omega(G)< 4$, $e = 3v - 6$ . It's well known no such graph available. **Could it be generalized?**

After massive computation on graph coloring, one conjecture come to me:

for $G = (v,e)$

if :

$\delta(G) > n,$

$ e \leq (n-1)v -n(n-1)/2, $

$K_n $ is not subgraph of $G$

then $G  $ $n$ colorable.

**No counterexample has been found though I don't believe it's true.**

Little surprised, even after making restriction much looser as below, no counterexample has been found.

if :

$ e \leq (n-1)v -n(n-1)/2, $

$\delta(G) >  n,$

$K_{n+1} $ is not subgraph of $G$

then $G  $ $n$ colorable.

if :

$ e \leq (n-1)v -n(n-1)/2, $

$\delta(G) \ge  n,$

$K_{n} $ is not subgraph of $G$

then $G  $ $n$ colorable.

Let $n = 4$, if conjecture is true, then 4-color theorem could be proved in  an elegant way.

**Could you give some advice to search counterexample in a proper direction?**

Comment: I think $\omega(G)< 4$ is false. Add disjoint $K_4$. If you want it connected add an edge from the K_4 to outer vertex.

Comment: @joro: are we sill speaking about the smallest graph with $\chi(G)=5$?